# "act the fool" vs "act like a fool"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I constructed the sentences like these below

> 1. Why are you always **acting** the fool?
> 2. Why are you always **acting like** a fool?

Which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

In short, both are correct.

- The phrase `act the fool` or `play the fool` is **an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/act+the+fool)** which means to behave playfully, often to amuse others. I personally interpret it as to act/play the fool role or to play the role of a fool.
- `Act like a fool` simply compares one's actions to a fool's actions. I.e., you can say act like a whale if that person does so, but I don't believe there is an idiom `act the whale`.